# Jquery Validaton using remote and Laravel 5.2 is not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, jquery-validation-engine, remote-validation

- I am trying to validate is email id exist or not, using remote in jquery validation,
  but its showing Object Not Found and error code is 404 in console.
- i think weather it is not taking url as route as per the laravel:

  so i tried this also url:  "{{ url('admin/check') }}",
- changed get to post but showing the same error

  ```
   //validation.js

   $("#person_data").validate
   ({ rules: {
              c_email: 
              {
               required: true,
               remote:{
                       type: 'get',
                       url: 'admin/check'}
                      }
              }
             }
          messages:{
                   c_email: {
                             required: "Please enter Email Address",
                             remote:  "Email already in use!"
                            }
                    }
   });


     //route.php

    Route::get('admin/check', 'CompanyController@check_pemail_exist');


       //controller

       public function check_pemail_exist()
       {

            $user_email= Input::get('c_email');
            $existing_users = User::where('email',$user_email)->first();

              if(count($existing_users)>0)
              {
                   return "false"; //already registered
              }
              else
              {
                   return "true";  //user name is available
              }
       }
  ```

getting error in console like this :

POST http://localhost:8080/admin/check 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to clear whether its a GET or POST method call.,

If its POST method you need to add csrf-token along with the request header.

[laravel csrf](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#csrf-protection)

If its GET method, you can directly check it by  http://localhost:8080/admin/check?c_email=test@gmail.com , if its working your remote vaidate method will work, there is nothing problem with laravel.

Comment: i am using GET only but its showing the error in console                                                                           
                       localhost/project/public/admin/companymaster/admin/check?c_email=ratnesh%40gmail.com 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Change  `url: 'admin/check'` to `url: '{{ url('admin/check') }}'` that's your problem!

Comment: sorry, but in post only i have mentioned that i used this but its showing the syntax error

Comment: Ok then try to add `var base_url="{{ url('/') }}";` where you add your validation.js (index.html or master page) and use `url: base_url+'/admin/check'`

Comment: but i want the to restrict message while i am updating form apart from email details